# SVG Rect Ignores Height?

Tags: css, svg

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zKsFC/) of a rectangle. I'd like to [move the height property to css](http://jsfiddle.net/zKsFC/1/) and well, it doesn't work and gives me a blank. It happens in firefox and chrome.

Is there a different name for it? I don't understand why I can't use a css file. The fill color works.

Working example.

css:

```
rect {
    fill:rgb(0, 0, 255);
    /*doesnt work height:100;*/
}
```

html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In SVG the x, y, width and height of `<rect>` elements are [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) rather than [CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). Only CSS properties can be styled using CSS.

Comment: ugh, alright. So does this mean I need to use javascript or something to add the attributes for every rect? I was hoping for something nice and clean like css.

Comment: @RobertLongson and which way would be the cleanest ? With markup all the size would be static and inside the html. By javascript, does this mean I should start learning jQuery for the dom manipulation, or can I do without it for the moment ?

Comment: By javascript I meant something like rect.setAttribute("x", "100"); which is just DOM, no jquery required.

Comment: The two URLs you give, SVG attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html and CSS properties: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html are identical, but are invoked to demonstrate the difference between the two. I don't understand.

Answer (score 6):

The `width` of a `<rect>` element isn't a CSS property in SVG, it's only usable as an attribute. It's for example like the `size` of a `<select>` element in HTML. You can only set it as an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

SVG doesn't have a straightforward support for CSS for setting shape dimensions.

However there's a workaround for rects, which can also be used to generate horizontal and vertical lines:

- Set width and height to 1, and use CSS transform: scale(width, height)
- Don't specify x,y location, and use transform: translate(x, y)

E.g.

```css
.svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
.rectangle {
  transform: scale(30, 10);
  fill: orange;
}
.horiz-line {
  transform: translate(15px,5px) scale(50, 1);
  fill: red;
}
.vert-line {
  transform: translate(10px, 5px) scale(1, 30);
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect class="rectangle" width="1" height="1" />
  <rect class="horiz-line" width="1" height="1" />
  <rect class="vert-line" width="1" height="1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround for symmetric rectangles:

```css
rect:hover {
  stroke-width: 20 !important;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect
    stroke-width="0"
    fill="blue" stroke="blue"
    x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"
  />
</svg>
```

(darkreader will use different colors for stroke and fill)