# Specifying an SVG rectangle's width and height in CSS

Tags: css, svg

Today is not my day for [understanding CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23320706/575530).

Given the following simple CSS

```
.EggBar {
    fill: teal;
}
```

and the following HTML fragment

```
<svg>
    <rect class="EggBar" width="20" height="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```

the rendered result is just what I'd expect: a teal rectangle, width 20 and height 100, within the SVG on the page.

However, if I change the two fragments to

```
.EggBar {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    fill: teal;
}
```

and

```
<svg>
    <rect class="EggBar" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```

i.e. I hand over responsibility for setting the width and the height of the rectangle from the SVG element to its CSS class, then the rectangle *is not* rendered - I'm guessing it ends up with width and height zero. Why? Why don't the two methods produce identical results?

Comment: See this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383014/svg-rect-ignores-height - Those width & height aren't CSS-props, but svg props

Comment: Thanks @pc-shooter, I'll add a duplicate flag

Comment: Please help with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319537/html-5-inline-svg-and-namespace-awareness-for-svg-dom

Comment: @GLES try putting a bounty on that question of yours if you want to attract more answers, that's worked well in the past for me.

Comment: Thanks :) but the question is eligible for bounty after 2 days... :(

Comment: if you do not set size for rect in SVG itself, it cannot be rescaled later with `width` and `height` in CSS . it has on first place no size at all .(**S** callable **V** ector **G** raphic) :)

Comment: @GCyrillus So if I set the attribute for the rect in SVG and then set the CSS height in code will the CSS new value work?

Comment: it should work , you may need as well to set the attribute viewbox to svg , and resize svg , depends if you want to keep ratio or stretch element

Comment: No, it won't ever work to set a height on a rectangle in CSS.  It's a completely different property.  **Width, height and position of SVG shapes should be considered as equivalent to the text of an HTML element -- it's the basic content material, not a style or presentation effect.**  If you need to change it dynamically, you'll need to use Javascript.  This is different from "fill" which is a [presentation attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes) -- a style property which can optionally be specified with XML instead of CSS.